# Need a value without quotation marks from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is my code:

```
router.post('/findmanychallengesbyid', auth, function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.ids){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Geen ids'});
  }

  var challengeData = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(req.body.ids).length; i++ ) {
    Challenge.findById(JSON.parse(req.body.ids)[i].toString().replace(/\"/g, ""), function (err, doc){
      challengeData.push(doc);
    });
  }

  res.json(challengeData);

});
```

Challenge is a schema from my nodejs app.

When I do res.json(JSON.parse(req.body.ids)) I get:

```
[
  "56313da58c5ba50300f2b4f0",
  "564cac9c097c07030038cac0",
  "563140668c5ba50300f2b4f3"
]
```

Challenge.findById requires this as input:

> 56313da58c5ba50300f2b4f0

Now it gets this as input:

> "56313da58c5ba50300f2b4f0"

So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: This question looks like you're trying to solve a small problem that's part of a bigger problem, and there may be a different simpler way of solving the bigger problem. What is your larger goal with this?

Comment: Regarding *this* problem, is `"563140668c5ba50300f2b4f3"` a console representation, or are `"` actually in the string?

Comment: unquoted `563140668c5ba50300f2b4f3` is not a valid represenation of anything in JavaScript. It would have to be treated as a string.

Comment: I have edited the op for more detailed info.

Comment: What does `req` look like? It's a javascript object that includes some unparsed string? Where does `Challenge` come from?

Comment: req is just from nodejs, the code is part of a API route in nodejs. Challenge is a schema.

Comment: There is no such JS syntax as `56313da58c5ba50300f2b4f0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search for an array of id's if I understand the code correctly.

The proper way to do is, is to use .find

```
router.post('/findmanychallengesbyid', auth, function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.ids){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Geen ids'});
  }

  Challenge.find({
    '_id': { $in: JSON.parse(req.body.ids)}
    }, function(err, docs){
      res.json(docs);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
.replace(/\"/g, "")
```

to replace the ""

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JSONValue to to String:

```
String.ValueOf(iets);
```

or you may use the replaceAll function of String Class

```
iets.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
```

This method replace all the double quotes which are present in your iets not the first and the last.

Example : "Hello" becomes Hello but if its as "He"llo" it should be He"llo according to your requirement but it becomes Hello. Mean to say that all the double quote replaced.